# How to get two arrays from php using mysqli,jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

i want the function(data) to get 2 attribute value from the database

This is the select option that display the display the address and contact value of the selected option in an input field

```
 $('#recipient').change(function(){  
        var FULL_NAME = $(this).val();  
        $.ajax({  
            url:"load_data.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{FULL_NAME:FULL_NAME},  
            success:function(data){  
                     $('#address').val(data);
                     $('#contact').val(data);  
            }  
        });

    });
```

and this is the load_data.php

```
<?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM recipient";
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {
        $output1 = $row["ADDRESS"];
        $output2 = $row["CONTACT"];
        $arr = array($output1,$output2);  
      }  
      echo $output1,$output2;
?>
```

How do i pass the $output1 into $('#address').val(data) and $output2 into $('#contact').val(data)

Comment: use json_encode and out put arr. the in js `data[0]`

Comment: concatenate the two string with a separator and in ajax use `split()` to get the two value separetly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('#recipient').change(function(){  
        var FULL_NAME = $(this).val();  
        $.ajax({  
            url:"load_data.php",  
            method:"POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{FULL_NAME:FULL_NAME},  
            success:function(data){  
                     $('#address').val(data['ADDRESS']);
                     $('#contact').val(data['CONTACT']);  
            }  
        });

});
```

and the load_data.php

```
<?php
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {
        $arr["ADDRESS"] = $row["ADDRESS"];
        $arr["CONTACT"] = $row["CONTACT"]; 
      }  
     echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```